# Elasticsearch and RSpec integration

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, testing, rspec, elasticsearch

I've used [sunspot](https://github.com/sunspot/sunspot) ruby gem in the past and to write integration tests I found some gems and tutorial that show how to integrate with RSpec and Cucumber ecosystem. Here are some examples:

- https://github.com/justinko/sunspot-rails-tester
- https://github.com/pivotal/sunspot_matchers
- https://github.com/sunspot/sunspot/wiki/RSpec-and-Sunspot

Is there something similar for Elasticsearch and ruby/rails?

It's not so hard to write some custom matchers and some before/after/around hooks which setup the whole stuff by myself (and in fact the above gems are not a big codebase) but maybe there is already something working.

I'm using [tire](https://github.com/karmi/retire) as ES client and I've already read its wiki which contains [some](http://blog.lucascaton.com.br/index.php/2012/08/01/how-to-test-elasticsearch-in-a-rails-application/) [hints](https://github.com/karmi/retire/wiki/Integration-Testing-Rails-Models-with-Tire) about testing

Comment: not that i know of...